# Random samples from each column of a data.frame

Tags: r, statistics, sample

I want to draw random sample from each row of a `data.frame` independently from other rows. Here is an example. This code selects the same column for each row but I require independent selection of columns for each row.

```
library(plyr)
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- mdply(data.frame(mean=c(10, 15)), rnorm, n = 5, sd = 1)
df1
  mean       V1       V2        V3        V4       V5
1   10 10.58553 10.70947  9.890697  9.546503 10.60589
2   15 13.18204 15.63010 14.723816 14.715840 14.08068
> df1[ , -1]
        V1       V2        V3        V4       V5
1 10.58553 10.70947  9.890697  9.546503 10.60589
2 13.18204 15.63010 14.723816 14.715840 14.08068
> sample(df1[, -1], replace = TRUE)
         V3       V2       V5        V4      V4.1
1  9.890697 10.70947 10.60589  9.546503  9.546503
2 14.723816 15.63010 14.08068 14.715840 14.715840
> t(apply(df1[, -1], 1, sample))
         [,1]      [,2]     [,3]     [,4]      [,5]
[1,] 10.70947  9.890697 10.60589 10.58553  9.546503
[2,] 14.71584 13.182044 14.08068 15.63010 14.723816
```

**Edited**

```
df1[ , -1]
            V1       V2        V3        V4       V5
    1 10.58553 10.70947  9.890697  9.546503 10.60589
    2 13.18204 15.63010 14.723816 14.715840 14.08068

sample(df1[, -1], replace = TRUE)
             V3       V2       V5        V4      V4.1
    1  9.890697 10.70947 10.60589  9.546503  9.546503
    2 14.723816 15.63010 14.08068 14.715840 14.715840
```

`sample(df1[, -1], replace = TRUE)` selects the  columns `V3`, `V2`, `V5`, `V4`, and `V4` for both rows. But I require that it could select  columns `V3`, `V2`, `V5`, `V4`, and `V4` for `first row` and/or any combinations of five columns for  `second row`.

Comment: `sample` will just scramble each row as you are doing it. E.g.: `t(apply(data.frame(rbind(1:5,1:5)), 1, sample))` Each row is scrambled independently though. Do you want to select different numbers of columns from each row?

Comment: Do you need `df1[sample(seq_along(1:ncol(df1))[-1])]`

Comment: @akrun - `df1[sample(names(df1[-1]))]`

Comment: @thelatemail: `df1[sample(names(df1[-1]))]` selects the same columns for each row as do `sample(df1[, -1], replace = TRUE)` and `t(apply(df1[, -1], 1, sample))`.

Comment: It is not clear what the expected output is.

Comment: @akrun: Please see my edits. Thanks

Comment: DId you mean the values in each row can be independent

Comment: @akrun: Yes values in each row can be independent from values of other rows.

Comment: So, why the `apply` code didn't work `t(apply(df1[,-1], 1, sample, replace=TRUE))`

Comment: @akrun: It works. Would you mind to change your comment to answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `apply` with `replace=TRUE` for the `sample`

```
 t(apply(df1[,-1], 1, sample, replace=TRUE))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could sample the column indices all at once and then use matrix subsetting to avoid having to use `apply`:

```
## Determine how many indices are required (nrow x (ncol - 1))
nsamp <- prod(dim(df1[, -1]))

## Sample from the number of desired columns, here 5 = ncol(df1[, -1])
mySamp <- sample.int(5, nsamp, replace = TRUE)

## Create a matrix of row and column indices
## Have to add 1 to mySamp to ignore first column of df1
myIdx <- cbind(rep(seq_len(nrow(df1)), ncol(df1) - 1), mySamp + 1)

## Return the corresponding values
matrix(df1[myIdx], nrow = nrow(df1))

#           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]     [,5]
# [1,]  9.890697 10.60589  9.546503  9.546503 10.70947
# [2,] 15.630099 14.71584 15.630099 14.723816 14.72382
```