# Random samples from each column of a data.frame containing NAs

Tags: r, random, statistics, sample

This is a follow up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31646131/707145). I want to draw random sample from each row of a `data.frame` independently from other rows. The `data.frame` may contains NAs as given in the given `data.frame` `df`.

```
set.seed(12345)
df1 <- c(rnorm(n=4, mean=0, sd=1), NA)
df2 <- rnorm(n=5, mean=10, sd=1)
df <- rbind(df1, df2)

t(apply(df, 1, sample, replace=TRUE))

         [,1]     [,2]       [,3]     [,4]    [,5]
df1 0.5855288       NA -0.1093033 0.709466      NA
df2 9.7238159 9.723816  8.1820440 9.723816 10.6301
```

From the first row I want to select four observations (non-empty columns) with replacement and from second row I want to select five observations (non-empty columns) with replacement independently from first selection. But my given code selects five observations with replacement from first row and five observations with replacement from second row.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right @akrun.

Comment: Perhaps `lst <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x[!is.na(x)], replace=TRUE));do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))`

Comment: Thanks @akrun for your helpful comment. Would you mind to change your comment to answer.

Comment: I updated the post with the new code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to `sample` only with the non-NA values.  In that case, `!is.na` can be useful to remove the NA values and then we `sample` on the remaining values.  The output will be a `list` ('lst') as the number of elements differ (4 and 5) for each row after the `sample`.

```
  lst <- apply(df, 1, function(x) sample(x[!is.na(x)], replace=TRUE))
```

If we need to reconvert the `list` to `matrix`, we can append 'NA' at the end to make the lengths same for each of the `list` elements and we use `rbind` to convert it back to `matrix`.

```
  do.call(rbind,lapply(lst, `length<-`, max(lengths(lst))))
```